# React build fails on AWS CodeBuild with TypeError in stylis-plugin-rtl

Tags: reactjs, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

In the last days I try to build my react app throughout AWS CodeBuild and in all attempts the build fail. When I build locally in my machine the yarn build command work fine!

The specs of the build environment on AWS Codebuild is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48CWv.png)

The output logs:

```
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:02:01 Running command npm run build

> @minimal/minimal-kit-react@4.3.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

TypeError: /codebuild/output/src861892420/src/node_modules/stylis-plugin-rtl/dist/stylis-rtl.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)

[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:36 Command did not exit successfully npm run build exit status 1
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:36 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:36 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:36 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:36 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:36 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:37 Expanding base directory path: build
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:37 Assembling file list
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:37 Expanding build
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:37 Expanding file paths for base directory build
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:37 Assembling file list
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:37 Expanding **/*
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:37 Found 248 file(s)
[Container] 2023/05/27 13:04:37 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
```

I try to use buildspec.yml file with yarn and only npm, in all the cases a have the same error.

Using yarn:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
    commands:
      - npm install yarn
      - yarn
      - yarn add eslint-config-react-app
  build:
    commands:
      - yarn build
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'build'
```

Using only npm:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on 'date'
      - npm run build
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'build'
```

I try to use ubuntu image in the build enviroment and I have the same error.
I also try to install different version of the stylis-plugin-rtl and I have the same error.

Comment: did you try uninstall current version u have with stylis-plugin-rtl and again install stylis-plugin-rtl@2.0.2? More info here: https://github.com/styled-components/stylis-plugin-rtl/issues/33

Comment: Yes! I try uninstall and reinstall other version and the problem persist. But this occurs only on the AWS CodeBuild, in my local machine the build occurs normally.